# Using :after element to make header that is rotated and height of the parent div

Tags: css, css-transforms

been struggling with this all afternoon. I want the black header to sit perfectly to the right of the quarter circles and dynamically fill the height. The colors are intended to be off screen and will use a rotate animation on mouseover to rotate them in.

You can check out the codepen here: https://codepen.io/Dawsraki/pen/LLrajZ

```
.quarter{
    position: fixed;
    width: 40vh;
    height: 40vh;
}
.quarter1{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}
.quarter1:after{
    content:"Home";
    width:40vh;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background:black;
    color:white;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the `rotate` with `translate` and set a proper `transform-origin`

```
transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);        /*  counter clockwise  */
transform-origin: center top;                      /*  defaults to center center  */
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJZVYN)

---

For clockwise rotation

```
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50%);
```